# javascript/angular readAsArrayBuffer security error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, upload, filereader

Hey guys I'm having an issue with file reader directive where on IE 11 I'm getting intermittent security error:

[image]

the directive code:

```
(function () {
var module = angular.module("new");
module.directive("freader", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            freader: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind("change", function (e) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var data = null;
                file.size = file.date;
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var array = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                    var result = Array.prototype.slice.call(array);
                    data = { data: result };
                    data.name = file.name;
                    if (data) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.freader = data;
                        });
                    }
                }
                if(file)
                   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            });
        }
    }
});})();
```

As I researched so far I created clean function:

```
<input type="file" freader="vm.file" onclick="clean(this)" />

function clean(val) {
    try {
        val.value = null;
    } catch (ex) { }
    if (val.value) {
        val.parentNode.replaceChild(val.cloneNode(true), val);
    }
}
```

I have also tried to set the input type to text and then back again to file but nothing really works, error always shows up after some time.

Not really sure how to handle this problem?

Comment: It is not possible to set  `.size` property of `File` object. `File` object does not have a `.date` property. You set the `.value` of the `<input type="file">` element to `null` at `onclick` handler of element.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is purpose of `scope: {
            freader: "="
        }`? Are you trying to reference `scope.filereader` at `scope.filereader = data;`? Why is `click` handler necessary?

Comment: sorry that was my typo it should be scope.freader = data;. I got onclick there as some other posts where advising to clean value as it's a common problem with IE.

Comment: Have not tried ie in some time. Unable to reproduce error. `click` handler is not necessary. You can call `.value = ""` when all other tasks have completed at `change` event

Comment: I have that tried already, the same thing is happening.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to read a file from local filesystem?

Comment: yes, in fact I'm trying to fix some legacy code.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to load a file from local filesystem at ie. Again, have not tried ie in some time. There may be a setting that will allow you to disable web security

Comment: I can load and read file, but when I do this for a several times it randomly fails.